# Having a problem updating table in Linq to Entities with update statement but not updating the table 

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a form with add, edit, and save buttons. The form also has a datagridview.

I have done this to update existing product entities and to add new product entities, then display the altered data in the datagridview.

When I click on edit button, the save button will be displayed and the statements that I have written in save button is executed.

New product entities add just fine.

My problem is that when I click on the edit button, anew row is added to datagridview  instead of updating the same row.

Is there any way to check the condition whether the available product in table is updating or adding a new product before adding  to table in entity framework?

```
    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        pictureBox1.Enabled = true;
        pictureBox1.Visible = true;
        Image image = pictureBox1.Image;
        byte[] bit = null;

        bit = imageToByteArray(image);
        product1 pd = new product1();

        string category = tbCategoryName.Text;
        string categorydesc = tbCategoryDescription.Text;

        var c = new category { category_Name = category, category_Description = categorydesc };

        pd.product_Name = tbProductName.Text;
        decimal price = Convert.ToDecimal(tbProductPrice.Text);
        pd.product_Price = price;
        pd.product_Description = tbProductdescription.Text;           
        pd.product_Image = bit;

        pd.category = c;


        tsgentity.SaveChanges();
        EquipmentFinder equipment = new EquipmentFinder();            
        equipment.productgridview.Refresh();           
        this.Close();
        equipment.ShowDialog(this);           

   }
```

Comment: Be careful when using a Data Context [I presume that's what **tgsentity** is] as if you use more than one without some life-cycle management you are bound to run into save issues.
Try to put a breakpoint and check out **pd**'s EntityState, if it is EntityState.Modified it should work, if not, refactor your code so that you only use one Data Context.

Comment: that is my dbcontext name and pd1 is object for table product..

Comment: Do you use any other dbcontext? Did you check pd.EntityState?

Comment: no this is only one dbcontext i use where do i check the pd.entitysate

Comment: Why did you remove the `AddToProducts` line in your edit? The code doesn't make sense anymore now: You're creating a new `product1` (`pd`) and a new `category` (`c`) and then do nothing with them. I also don't understand why you add new entities in your `Save` event handler instead of your `Add` event. `Save` should save and `Add` should add, shouldn't it? You have an `Add` button and an `Edit` button. Isn't their purpose exactly to distinguish between creating new and updating entites? Perhaps the problem is better to understand when you show what you have in your `Add` and `Edit` events.

Comment: @slauma the problem has been solved....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an example. What your need to do is pull the current object from collection you are editing/saving using linq and then make the changed on the retrieved object and then update i.e.

```
public bool UpdateCustomer(Customer customer){   
    Customer cust = entities.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.ID == customer.ID);  
    cust.Forname = customer.Forename;   
    cust.Surname = customer.Surname   
    entities.SaveChanges(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the event handlers for those buttons? Are they wired into the correct buttons? It sounds like your edit button is firing the event handler for new products and it sounds like the add button is firing the event handler for editing a product. I would definitely check that first instead of looking for a work-around or hack to tolerate that.

Comment: @jlafry would you pls help with any idea